# Laravel guest middleware

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.8

I have a page in my web app that should be blocked from logged in users. Similar to how a login or register page should not be accessible to already logged in users. I accomplished this by using guest middleware in controller constructor.

```
$this->middleware("guest")->only("page_action"); // like this
```

In this setup, if logged in user tries to visit that page they get redirected to home page. But I need to show a 404 not found page instead of redirecting. How can I do that?

In short, how can I make a page accessible to guest only and make it look like it does not exist to logged in users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method just check if the user is loggedIn, if then abort to 404 like below...

```
if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check()) {
    return abort(404);
}

#Rest of the code is for guest user.....
#
```

Answer (score 6):

The guest logic is inside inside `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`.

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    abort(404)
}

return $next($request);
```

Otherwise, you need to create a new middleware like @Atiqur suggested.